# How to make changes to only one element with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

The project I am working on requires to added a new element and make changes to the element using a edit button. How can I target only element with same class and make changes to it without effecting the other elements with the same class?

**[CodePen example](http://codepen.io/Stakeley/pen/VmjyVR)**.

```
var $input = $("#change");
var $btn = $("#add");
var $btne = $("#edit");
var $content = $("#content");
$btne.hide();


$btn.click( function(){

 var typedInfo = document.getElementById("change").value;
 var item = $('<li></li>');
 item.append(typedInfo);
 $content.append(item);


 $content.on("click","li", function(){
  });

 item.click(function(){
    var clickedItem = $(this);
     $btne.show();
     item.text(" ");
     var typeNew = $('<input type="text" id="newInput" value = "edit">')
   typeNew.click( function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
     item.append(typeNew);
       $btne.click( function(){
        var editedInput = document.getElementById("newInput").value;
        clickedItem.text(editedInput);
        $btne.hide();
   });
 });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First the `id` should be unique in the same document so you should replace the duplicate ones by class, e.g :

```
var typeNew = $('<input type="text" class="newInput" value = "edit">')
```

Using `document.getElementById("newInput")` will target all the elements with this `id`, Use `e.target` to target just the clicked one :

```
var editedInput = e.target.value;
```

Instead of :

```
var editedInput = document.getElementById("newInput").value;
```

You should pass the event `e` to the click :

```
$btne.click( function(e){
//____________________^
    var editedInput = e.target.value;
    clickedItem.text(editedInput);
    $btne.hide();
});
```

Hoep this helps.

```js
var $input = $("#change");
var $btn = $("#add");
var $btne = $("#edit");
var $content = $("#content");

$btne.hide();

$btn.click( function(){
  var typedInfo = $("#change").val();
  var item = $('<li></li>');

  item.append(typedInfo);

  $content.append(item);
});

$content.on("click","li", function(){
  var clickedItem = $(this);
  var typeNew = $('<input type="text" class="newInput" value="'+clickedItem.text()+'">')
  $btne.show();

  $(this).html(typeNew);

  typeNew.click( function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});

$btne.click( function(e){
  $($content).find('li>input').each(function(){
    $(this).parent().text($(this).val());
  })

  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
ul {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

li{
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="change" value="Type Here">
<button id="add">Add Button</button>
<button id="edit">Edit Button</button>

<ul id="content"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the elements will be added in an array-like manner and you want to edit the last one every time, you can use the :last selector

```
$('.class:last')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give the element that you want to change a unique ID. It can still have the same class, but you could reference it by referring to its ID instead of its class name.